# Mongoose $text field error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use `$text in mongoose but it's always showing me the error.

Model/Schema:

```
var thSchema2=new Schema({
    userid:{ type: String, unique: true,index: true},
    password:String,
    name:String,
    phone:String
});
```

My query in the controller:

```
Model
    .find( { $text : { $search : "mo"} })
    .exec(function(err, results) {
        if(err){
            console.log("eroro ocured");
            res.send(401);
        }else{
            console.log("foud");
            res.json(results);
        }
    });
```

It's always showing me error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missing `text` index in your schema, if you want the search the field `name`, then add text index as below

```
thSchema2.index({'name': 'text'});
```

Comment: I want to search userid,and I have already specified index:true in schema

Comment: @MohammedGadiwala, try to use `thSchema2.index({'userid': 'text'});`, the `index: true` is different with text index.

Comment: @MohammedGadiwala, here is one discussion like about text index in mongoose, https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1401